# Añadir una etiqueta html solo cuando variable exista en laravel blade

Tags: html, laravel

tengo unas etiquetas html que se están añadiendo con un foreach, dentro de ese foreach hay otras etiquetas que no siempre deben estar presentes, ahora lo estoy haciendo así

```
   <h2 class="product-name"><i class="{{isset($locationGroup->name) ? 'fa - fa-folder' : ''}}"></i> {{$locationGroup->name ?? ''}}</h2>
```

lo cual funciona bien, pero el problema es que aún así esto me está generando etiquetas vacías en lugares donde el isset es falso, ejemplo

```
<h2 class="product-name"><i class=""></i> </h2>
```

quiero que eso no ocurra, quiero que con la condición `isset($locationGroup->name) ?` pueda añadir toda la etiqueta HTML "del tirón" para que así cuando dé falso, no añada nada. Cuando intenté meter todo entre las llaves de laravel todo terminó saliendo como texto

ejemplo

```
  {{isset($locationGroup->name) ? '<h2 class="product-name"> <i class="fa - fa-folder"></i>' . $locationGroup->name . '</h2>' : ''}}
```

el resultado de esto es todo un texto donde nada se convierte en etiqueta, es decir esto pero escrito de manera literal

```
<h2 class="product-name"> <i class="fa - fa-folder"></i>testedit</h2>
```

Comment: isset verifica que la variable exista, no evalua el valor de la variable

Comment: `$locationGroup->name == true ? 'fa fa' : ''` podrias probar algo asi

Comment: @IgmerRodriguez sí, mala mía, aún así la variable no existe, de hecho es el funcionamiento correcto verificar que exista y por ende no se agrega, pero lo que quiero es añadir toda la etiqueta h2 del tirón, se entiende? o sea "meter" toda la etiqueda h2 dentro del isset porque ahora mismo lo que viene siendo el 'fa fa' no se agrega, que es lo esperado, pero quiero replicar lo mismo con toda la etiqueta para que no se agregue nada

Comment: tendrias que evaluar la condicion antes de crear la etiqueta

Answer (score 0):

con @if pude hacerlo :)

```
 @if((isset($locationGroup->name)))
      <h2 class="product-name"> <i class="fa - fa-folder"></i> {{$locationGroup->name}} </h2>
 @endif
```

Answer (score 0):

Puedes usar la función `empty` de **php**:

```
@if(!empty($locationGroup->name))
      <h2 class="product-name"> <i class="fa - fa-folder"></i> {{$locationGroup->name}}</h2>
@endif
```

La función `empty` valida si la variable esta vacia o es falsa, por lo que solo hace falta negarla con `!` y listo. Yo uso esta función para todo en lugar de isset.

Espero sea de ayuda!